# VHDL signal assignment

Tags: vhdl

Assume having this code and the diagram I attached..

```
entity t_trigger is
     port (Test, Reset, clk, en : in std_logic;
     Q_out: out std_logic);
end t_trigger;

architecture beh_t_trigger of t_trigger is
signal temp: std_logic ;

begin
 process (Reset, clk)
 begin
 if (clk'event and clk='1') then
  if Reset='1' then
   temp <= '0';
  elsif en = '1' then
   temp <= Test xor temp;
  end if;
 end if;
end process;
Q_out <= temp;
end beh_t_trigger;
```

[image]

what is the state of Q_out at the end of the sequence? If the first condition is true then we skip the second?
What is the initial value of temp?
I cant understand what we assign to it since at first none of the "if" conditions is true..

Comment: `temp` is not initialised, so it's initial value is `'U'`. That's probably not what you're asking; if not, you need to add more detail to the question.

Comment: I have to know what the `Qout` is. Without knowing temp it's not possible..

Comment: I mentioned above all the details..

Comment: In addition to @scary_jeff's comment, it will transition from 'U' (assuming it isn't initialised) to '0' on the first clock edge shown, as Reset is '1'

Comment: @gsm but en is also `1`

Comment: So shouldn't temp be 1 after the clck edge ?

Comment: So the actual question is "what is the state of `Q_out` at the end of the sequence?`. You might want to write this in your question.

Comment: if/elsif will typically infer priority logic. Ergo, Reset has a higher precedence than en

Comment: @gsm "Reset has a higher precedence than en" I didnt understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Since first if condition is evaluated, and it was correct, the elsif case is skipped. Since at first reset was `1` at clock edge, you got temp `1`  https://image.ibb.co/fpQzAa/Clipboard_image_2017_03_15_21_02_39.png

Comment: I get it now! Much appreciated. I changed the question so you could answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the following image, looks horrible but would hopefully explain the whole process for the answer;

There are 5 clock rising edges to which your logic reacts, and except the first one, you have `Reset` value `0`, therefore first you get the `Q_out` value as `0`, rest is always the result of `temp xor Test signal` for `Q_out`, the line I drew there represents the xor operation between those values, however ugly, I hope this was useful :)

The initial value of `temp` is `U`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897143/is-initialization-necessary/6898053#6898053), and up until you get a rising clock edge, you shouldn't worry about its value anyway, the initial out signals of your entity would probably be `0` if it were on a hardware, but on simulation you can assume it only as `U`, if you are worried about the out signal before the clock event, you can assign some initial value to it, but will be overwritten after first clock edge obviously.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the "state" of `Q_out` as the waveform progresses, I hacked together a testbench (using rough timings) to indicate the output.

[image: rough testbench]

Note the "uninitialised" state of temp.

Regarding the logic behind why when `Reset` is asserted, we ignore the secondary branch of logic (ie. if `en` is high). `if`/`elsif` type statements tend to infer priority logic. This is demonstrated below by the RTL generated from your code.

[image: priority logic]

You can see from the logic that, if the `Reset` signal is ever asserted, the `D` input on the `temp` flop will always be `'0'`.